# Array of structs with dynamic allocation runs very slow in C in comparison to Python

Tags: python, c, graph-theory

I "glue" together (with a help of other SO users) a small C program that maps string labels to integer labels in a edgelist data structure. For instance, for input file

```
Mike Andrew
Mike Jane
John Jane
```

the program outputs

```
1 2
1 3
4 3
```

However, I mapped huge edgelist files and unfortunately the program runs very slow in comparison to Python alternative. Below I pasted both programs, in C and Python. I kindly ask for a pointers how to improve speed of the C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Initial number of maximal lines in a file
enum { MAXL = 200};

typedef struct {
    unsigned int first;
    unsigned int second;
} edge;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int hashed;
     char **map;
} hash;


int insertInMap(hash *map, char *entry)
{
  int i =0;
  for (i=0;i<map->hashed;i++)
  {
    if (strcmp(map->map[i],entry) == 0)
    return i+1;
  }
  /* Warning no boundary check is added */
  map->map[map->hashed++] = strdup(entry);   
  return map->hashed;
}

int main() {
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  char node1[30];
  char node2[30];
  int idx = 0;
  int i, n = 0, maxl = MAXL;

  edge *edges;
  hash map;

  edges = malloc(MAXL * sizeof(edge));
  map.map = malloc(MAXL * sizeof(char*));
  map.hashed = 0;

  fp = fopen("./test.txt", "r");

  while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", &node1, &node2) == 2) {
    if (++n == maxl) { /* if limit reached, realloc lines  */
      void *tmp = realloc (edges, (maxl + 40) * sizeof *edges);
      void *tmp1 = realloc (map.map, (maxl + 80) * sizeof(char*));
      if (!tmp) {     /* validate realloc succeeded */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        break;      /* on failure, exit with existing data */
      }
      edges = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to lines */

      map.map = tmp1;
      maxl += 40;     /* update maxl to reflect new size */
    }
    edges[idx].first = insertInMap(&map,node1);
    edges[idx].second = insertInMap(&map,node2);
    idx++;
  }

  fclose(fp);

  for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
    printf("%d -- %d\n", edges[i].first, edges[i].second);
  }


  free(edges);

  return 0;
}
```

The corresponding Python alternative:

```
import fileinput

i = 0
cui2int = {}

for line in fileinput.input():    
    (cui1, cui2) = line.split()
    if cui1 in cui2int:
        int1 = cui2int[cui1]
    else:
        i += 1
        cui2int[cui1] = i
        int1 = i

    if cui2 in cui2int:
        int2 = cui2int[cui2]
    else:
        i += 1
        cui2int[cui2] = i
        int2 = i

    print(int1, int2)
```

**EDITED AND ADDED**

Below is modified code using the GLib hash implementation. I improved performance, but unfortunately still have troubles with the output which should be

```
1 2
1 3
4 3
```

instead of

```
0 0
0 1
1 1
```

Could somebody please take a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  GHashTable *table;
  table = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);

  FILE *fp = NULL;
  char node1[30];
  char node2[30];

  fp = fopen("./test.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", &node1, &node2) == 2) {
    char *key1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    char *key2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    uint32_t* value = (uint32_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    key1 = g_strdup(node1);
    key2 = g_strdup(node2);
    *value = i;

    uint32_t *x;
    if (g_hash_table_contains(table, key1)) {
      x = (uint32_t *)g_hash_table_lookup(table, key1);
    } else {
      i++;
      g_hash_table_insert(table, (gpointer)key1, (gpointer)value);
      x = (uint32_t *)value;
    }

    uint32_t *y;
    if (g_hash_table_contains(table, key2)) {
      y = (uint32_t *)g_hash_table_lookup(table, key2);
    } else {
      g_hash_table_insert(table, (gpointer)key2, (gpointer)value);
      y = (uint32_t *)value;
    }
    printf("%d -- %d\n", *x, *y);
  }

  fclose(fp);

  g_hash_table_destroy(table);
  table = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the Python version doesn’t do a linear search for each entry like the C version does. Even if there’s words like “hash” and “map” the C version is just an array of strings with linear search. It will be slow.

Comment: You are using the word "hash" in your program but there is no actual hashing going on, just a linear search which is very slow. You need to find out what "hashing" means and implement a hash table.

Comment: Maybe time to try a [trie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074081/map-edgelist-with-string-node-labels-to-integer-labels/56074600#56074600), as I said in my answer a few days ago. Easier to code, easier to maintain, easier to reuse :-).

Comment: @m.raynal Sure, but first with hash.

Comment: I hope that I made an effort and re-implemented the initial program using the GLib hash table. Could somebody please take a look why the counting doesn't work correctly.

Comment: the code posted for the first C example results in LOTS of critical warnings,  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: the first C example is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>` for the functions: `strdup()` and `strcmp()`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `uint32_t* value = (uint32_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));`  1) In C, The heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` return type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp = fopen("./test.txt", "r");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", &node1, &node2) == 2) {`  When using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because these specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also assures there will not be a buffer overflow with the attendant undefined behavior

Comment: OT:  regarding: `char *key1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);`  The expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing the `sizeof(char)` expression from every call to a heap allocation function.

Answer (score 6):

Your "hash" in C operates more like a linked list, with linear insertion and lookup. On the other hand, Python's dictionary is industrial-strength with O(1) average insertions and lookups (the `in` operator). If you're writing a hashmap from scratch in C, there's a good deal of theory you're going to need to put into practice in order to begin approaching [Python's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c) in terms of performance.

In my opinion, the best bet is to write your code in C++ if possible and use an [`unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/). This is the best of both worlds: all the work has already been done for you, yet you don't need to make performance compromises.

If you are set on (or stuck with) C, there are quite a few resources on the internet, but I'm hesitant to post any links here since I can't vouch for their quality. It should be an educational endeavor.

Answer (score 6):

The two programs are using fundamentally different data structures with different time complexity. The python program is using a dictionary which is a highly tuned hash- table with *O*(*1*) amortized performance for lookup and deletion.

So the python program is running with *O*(*number of words*) asymptotic complexity.

Now, talking about your C program what you have tried to create is essentially just an array of key-value pairs. Inserting or retrieving the keys takes *O*(*size of the array*) here since you can potentially loop through the array till the end to find a match.

If you do some math, it turns out to be *O*((*number of words*)<sup>*2*</sup>).

C++ has built-in Hash-table implementation named [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), you can use that if you have no trouble switching to C++.   Or check out  this question on SO to learn writing your own hash table in C. [What is a hash table and how do you make it in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930046/what-is-a-hash-table-and-how-do-you-make-it-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that despite the name, it isn't a working hash table. You chew through the map with a linear search which is very slow. What you should do instead:

- Set the hash table size to a fixed size. Avoid any solution based on realloc.
- Come up with a hashing function to determine table index. There should be plenty of code examples on the net using strings.
- Implement a method for storing/checking an index. This could be storing in the next table index available, or by implementing "chaining", where each index is a linked list, etc.